# The specified program requires a new version of Windows. (Exception from HRESULT:0x8007047E)

Tags: workflow

I have an ListAdded event handler in which I'm associating OOB Approval workflow if any list is created based on my custom list definition.

As soon as the list is created, SharePoint throws this error:

Sorry, something went wrong
The specified program requires a new version of Windows. (Exception from HRESULT:0x8007047E)

But when I go and see, the list is created successfully and workflow is associated just fine!

The exact same code works just fine, if i add it as a feature receiver

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Sanjay

Comment: In further investigation, it turned out that this is working fine for OOB document libraries and one of my custom list definition. So I'm getting this error on only lists created based on ONE custom list definition.

Comment: Well, it turned out that in my custom list definition's schema.xml file I set "ModeratedList=True" to enable content approval on the list. That somehow caused the problem.
So, I removed that attribute, set content approval through my code in my ListAdded event receiver and redeployed the solution and everything worked!.